# Confusion on when list elements get modified during for loop in python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1])
b = np.array([2])
for i in [a,b]:
    i+=1
print(a)
print(b)
```

This generates the output

```
[2]
[3]
```

But

```
a = 1
b = 2
for i in [a,b]:
    i+=1
print(a)
print(b)
```

This generates the output

```
1
2
```

Why does this difference in behavior exist? In which cases can I assume elements accessed in for loop will modify original variable?

Comment: Difference between mutable and immutable objects.

Comment: A *for* loop in Python is a repeated execution of assignment statements, so that this has little to do with *for*.

Comment: no need to involve numpy, you can try 1st example with `a = [1]`... though `[1] + 1` would throw a helpful Exception about mixing types

Comment: @Aprillion No they won't. Python lists cannot be added with numericals. Works for numpy arrays as arrays can be broadcasted with scalars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code, `a` and `b` are each a name for a one-dimensional, one-entry numpy array. When you build the list `[a, b]` in your `for` statement, the list contains those arrays, so `i` in your loop becomes an array. The key point is the next: when the line `i+=1` is executed, Python adds `1` to the array. Numpy intercepts this command and uses a universal function (also called a ufunc) to add `1` to each member of the array. So each array is changed. However, `a` and `b` are still names for those arrays, so `a` and `b` are each changed, and you get your results.

In your second code, `a` and `b` are each a name for a numeric constant. When the list is built, it contains those constants. When the line `i+=1` is executed, `1` is added to the constant, but *since the constant is immutable* the result is just thrown away. Thus `a` and `b` are not changed.

So the short answer is: your first code uses mutable values in a list, while the second used immutable values in list. These behave differently in Python.